# How to install Cron on EC2 Instance

Tags: cron, amazon-ec2, yum

Does Cron come preinstalled on the EC2 linux instances, or do I have to install it separately from yum or anything?

Comment: why was this question closed? I would've been happy to provide further info if asked, and I couldn't find the info anywhere else.

Comment: Seems on topic according to the FAQ which specifically covers "software tools commonly used by programmers". Given both EC2 (arguably) and cron (definitely) qualify, I agree it's harsh to close the question.

Comment: @Roger I don't agree, because `cron` is not really a tool used for *programming*, using it is a classical administration task.

Comment: @Waldheinz but the FAQ doesn't say the tool needs to be "used for programming", it specifically says "used by programmers". I concede it is close to the line, but it struck me as a fair question to ask - possibly because I use EC2 and cron quite a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends completely on the instance you start from. Most if not all the ones I have used tend to have it, but if you are using one that doesn't have it, just install it ;-)